# How to add URL parameters to JSON web service call - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, web-services

I'm trying to fetch information from a JSON web service with this code, using SBJsonParser API:

```
 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"]];

// Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But I need to add to the web service URL two parameters, user and password, with their values, so the URL will be "http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json?user=name&password=test". I have searched information about APIs to do it but I wasn't successful.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the values in variables, correct? If so, just use the stringWithFormat: method of NSString.

Replace:

```
@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"
```

With:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json?user=%@&password=%@", user, password]
```

Comment: -1 The other answers are correct: For example:[NSString stringWithFormat : @"http:\//twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json?user=%@&password=%@", @"user", @"pas=?/word"] would result in: "http:\//twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json?user=user&password=pas=?/word" There is no proper URL escaping in this solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json?user=%@&password=%@", @"name", @"test"]]];
```

Substitute your own variables for `@"name"` and `@"test"` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *user = @"user";
NSString *password = @"password";

NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json?user=%@&password=%@", user, password];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlStr]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way.

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"];

 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:"@POST"] // Or get, push, put

 NSString theRquest_Body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?user=%@&password=%@",
                           [user stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                           [password stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]],

 [theRequest setHTTPBody:[theRequest_body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```